# Is it possible to use the AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient with embedded DynamoDBEmbedded for testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I try to write local tests against DynamoDb using the async client. How do I target it at the embedded version of the local DynamoDb?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use Embedded? I believe your use case fits better with launching a server version of DynamoDB Local:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.server.DynamoDBProxyServer;

final String[] localArgs = { "-inMemory" };
DynamoDBProxyServer server = ServerRunner.createServerFromCommandLineArgs(localArgs);
server.start();
AmazonDynamoDBAsync dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient();
dynamodb.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000");
dynamodb.listTables();
server.stop();
```

Comment: I don't think so, cos using a server you use also a port, which is a limited resource which I don't want to use in a test.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think DynamoDBEmbedded currently supports Async client, I'll take your use case and make it into a feature request for DynamoDB. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: Thanks, I also realized that the async client does not support the document API. What a pity. Thanks for opening a case

Comment: @DanielaMiao was there any progress made on this? Is the feature supported yet?